# Fine tune Flan T5 to build a SlackBot

Tags: machine-learning, python, gpt, huggingface, finetuning

I want to create a Slack chatbot that will be able to "somehow" mock a "ChatGPT like" behavior.

I want the bot to be able:

1. answer questions
2. understand from context
3. summarize info

I don't want to use OpenAI as I don't want to expose the data externally.
I've the relevant HW (GPUs) dedicated VM so at this aspect I'm good.
I took a look at this Notebook: https://github.com/amrrs/LLM-QA-Bot/blob/main/LLM_Q%26A_with_Open_Source_Hugging_Face_Models.ipynb

and thought using it as a guidance but the results are not good.
Basically I'm scrapping the history (conversations) from relevant channels and turn them into txt documents.

I feel like I'm missing something so I must ask this "very newbie" question:

Does fine-tuning a model mean adding more data to the model?

In my example it's very likely there will be new  terms that are not in the original model.
Do I need to do something about it?

Is this article addresses this issue https://www.philschmid.de/fine-tune-flan-t5 ?

I feel like I'm very confused by it and every direction will be great.